# Asp.Net MVC Javascript functions not working in Razor if statement

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm returning View from my action after post event and doing some javascript things in view. But javascript function calls not working in razor if statement.

```
        $.post("@Url.Action("Login", "Account")",
            accountObject,
            function(result) {
                $.unblockUI();
                if (result.isSuccess) {
                    var object = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.CrmIntegrationModel));
                    $.post("@Url.Action("File")",
                        object,
                        function(resultData) {
                            @if (!Model.IsFileViewModelEmpty)
                            {
                                var model = Model.UploadFileViewModel.PortalEntity as Task;
                                if (!Model.UploadFileViewModel.HasError)
                                {
                                    @:alert("Worked! ");
                                    if (model != null)
                                    {
                                        var task = model;
                                        if (task.State != State.Open)
                                        {
                                            <text>
                                                $.blockUI({ target: '#uploadPanel', message: null });
                                                $(swal({
                                                    title: "Warning",
                                                    text:
                                                        "File can not be uploaded for task that status is not open.",
                                                    type: "warning",
                                                    confirmButtonClass: "btn-warning",
                                                    confirmButtonText: "OK"
                                                }));
                                            </text>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            @: LoadDocumentTypes();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        @: LoadDocumentTypes();
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <text>
                                        $.blockUI({ message: null });
                                        $(swal({
                                            title: "Warning",
                                            text: '@Html.Raw(Model.UploadFileViewModel.ErrorMessage)',
                                            type: "warning",
                                            allowOutsideClick: false,
                                            showConfirmButton: false
                                        }));
                                    </text>
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
```

When I pass`if (!Model.UploadFileViewModel.HasError)` statement as true my `@:alert("Worked !");` not working. Also below lines `@: LoadDocumentTypes();` function call not working. How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Check the HTML that outputs. Your if statement should be throwing an error that is displayed in the console.

Comment: No error displaying in console. When I checked my html output my post callback function codes in ` function(resultData) {` is empty. Is it normal ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant your `alert`, not the `if`. The `@:alert("!Model.UploadFileViewModel.HasError");` does not utilize the value of `HasError`, but it _should_ be printed as a string in the generated HTML.

Comment: I did not really want my `@:alert("!Model.UploadFileViewModel.HasError");` to work this way. I don't want from it to utilize value, put this just worked line before this, so as a flag. But in my html output there is anything in `function(resultData) {}` function. Is the reason of this every javascript alerts and codes are in  C# if statement like `@if (!Model.IsFileViewModelEmpty)` ?

Comment: Correct. Razor executes the C# to determine what HTML (or JavaScript) to output to the page. So if you're using C# `if` statements around JavaScript blocks, they won't be sent to the client unless the condition is met. You should remove the `@` and just write plain JavaScript in there.

Comment: Ok I can use javasctipt if statement but this time how can I check model properties ?

Comment: By using Razor to inline the values into your JavaScript. You'll need to check out some tutorials on Razor. Best practice has putting the properties into hidden inputs with Razor, then reading them with JavaScript in an external file.